# matplotlib coordinates format

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

I have simple plot like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pt_no = [1,2,3]
coord_x = [6035763.111, 6035765.251, 6035762.801]
coord_y = [6439524.100, 6439522.251, 6439518.298]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(coord_y, coord_x, marker='x')
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
for i, txt in enumerate(pt_no):
    ax.annotate(txt, (coord_y[i], coord_x[i]))

plt.show()
```

but coordinates displayed in bootom-right corner of plot window as you move or hold cursor over the figure look like 6.43953e + 06.
How can I have my input coordinates displayed exactly as-is, for example
6439518.298 instead 6.43953e + 0

?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ax.fmt_xdata` attribute can be set to a function that formats the displayed string.

For example:

```
ax.fmt_xdata = lambda x: "{0:f}".format(x)
ax.fmt_ydata = lambda x: "{0:f}".format(x)
```

Comment: But one more question: As you examine my code you'll see I swapped axes passing my coordinate x, y as y, x to matplotlib to make my plot north-oriented. As result my coords are inversely displayed in plot window. Can it be easily changed?

Answer (score 8):

You can also completely override the default labeling by setting `format_coord`

```
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y: "({0:f}, ".format(y) +  "{0:f})".format(x)
```

[example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html), [api doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord)

Comment: Thanks a lot it's great hint, which will allow me to get everything I needed in this matter.