# How do I change the data display format for a imshow plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Or more specifically, how can I change the [659] on the upper-right corner to '659 degrees' or something like that ?

[image]

I have checked all the threads mentioned in the following reply: [matplotlib values under cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754931/matplotlib-values-under-cursor). However, all of them seem to address the x,y location of the cursor. I am interested in changing the data-value. I could not find a reply or related documentation in the api.

I have tried both `format_coord(x, y)` and `format_cursor_data(data)` but neither of them seem to be working.

Thanks,
Sarith

PS: My code is in multiple modules and is a part of gui application. I can share relevant sections if that would be of any help in answering this.

Comment: The weird thing is that usually it doesn' even show x and y coordinates, so you must already have a function for that..

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y: 'x={:.2f}, y={:.2f}, z={:.2f}'.format(x,y,data[int(y + 0.5),int(x + 0.5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (I wanted to get rid of the data and send it to somewhere else in a tkinter widget).
I figured out the `ax.format_coord` was'nt being called, the one you have to change is the one at `matplotlib.artist.Artist`
this worked for me:

```
    def format_cursor_data(self,data):            
        return 'new_data'
    matplotlib.artist.Artist.format_cursor_data=format_cursor_data
```

Comment: You also can reassign this function onto AxesImage object returned from imshow: img = p.imshow(my_image); img.format_cursor_data = format_cursor_data

Answer (score 0):

By modifying an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html) from matplotlib I got this code:

This displays x,y, and z value with a **degrees** after z.

You should be able to easily modify it, or copy the relevant functions to make it work on your side.

You said you already tried `format_coord`, maybe you forgot to set the funtion? (*second last line*)

```
"""
Show how to modify the coordinate formatter to report the image "z"
value of the nearest pixel given x and y
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 10*np.random.rand(5, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')

numrows, numcols = X.shape


def format_coord(x, y):
    col = int(x + 0.5)
    row = int(y + 0.5)
    if col >= 0 and col < numcols and row >= 0 and row < numrows:

        #get z from your data, given x and y
        z = X[row, col]

        #this only leaves two decimal points for readability
        [x,y,z]=map("{0:.2f}".format,[x,y,z])

        #change return string of x,y and z to whatever you want
        return 'x='+str(x)+', y='+str(y)+', z='+str(z)+" degrees"
    else:
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f' % (x, y)

#Set the function as the one used for display
ax.format_coord = format_coord
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. But this doesn't do it. It just displays something like "x=0.01, y=0.02  z=0.40 degrees [3.4]" (which is actually confusing). What I meant was something like than "x=0.01, y=0.02, 3.4 degrees". Perhaps I am asking for too much :/

Comment: Where do you get the [3.4] from? Is it automatically generated?
Try changing `return 'x='+str(x)+', y='+str(y)+', z='+str(z)+" degrees"` to `return 'x='+str(x)+', y='+str(y)+', z='+"Deg: "`. This should then at least display  `"x=0.01, y=0.02, Deg: [3.4] "`

Comment: Well, it just shows up on its own. I am using matplotlib 1.5.1. Here is the screenshot from your code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aim7h7o866ht4oq/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @SarithSubramaniam well that is... weird. You could remove `str(z)` resulting in `"x=0.01, y=0.02, degrees [3.4] "`.
I would guess there is a code fragment somewhere which causes this, because I can't get it to appear on my matplotlib :/

Comment: This is one of the new features in 1.5.  The `[]` are hard-coded into the move callback in the `Toolbar` (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2826 ).  You could sub-class and override that method or monkey-patch the `format_cursor_data` method on your image artist.

Comment: @tcaswell Thank you ! That meets my requirement perfectly. If you post this as a reply, I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Emmm, Sarith, I am also facing the problem but a little trick helped me out.  I still used this function:

`your_imshow.format_coord = lambda x, y: 'x={:.5f}, y={:.2f}, amplitude='.format(x,y)`

It pretends to add label before the bracket. Yeah, it is an easy but not essential way to change the presentation form, but it works to me. I hope this could also benefit others.