# Disable coordinates from the toolbar of a Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am working in a project using PyQt4 and Matplotlib libraries.I created a matplotlib figure and i added a toolbar.

Is there any way to disable the coordinates that are shown in it? I mean these:

[image]

I want to do this, because i am going to add some buttons in the toolbar and I need this space.

This is the code of the matplotlib figure:

```
class Figure(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.linedit = SelectData(self)

    self.mainWidget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas, 10)

    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(211)
    self.axes.grid(False)

    #I added this toolbar
    self.navigation_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2(self.figure_canvas, self)
    self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.navigation_toolbar)
```

I am new in python, so i hope you can help me. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reassign the axes [`format_coord`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord) to show anything you like (see, for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666889/588071) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35750602/588071)).

So to disable it altogether, you could set it to an empty string, like this:

```
self.axes.format_coord = lambda x, y: ""
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works!! I did not find these answers when i looked before.