# Disable value of pixels from toolbar on matplot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

As read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012602/disable-coordinates-from-the-toolbar-of-a-matplotlib-figure?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750332/change-format-of-coordinate-text-in-status-bar/35750602#35750602), they use `format_coord` to disable coordinates or change format from the toolbar. 
Using `axe.format_coord = lambda x, y: ''` as in the linked question, removed the coordinates, which is fine. However, I also want to disable the value of pixels: [image]

I then tried to use

```
axe.format_coord = lambda x, y,z:''
```

but that gave an error:

```
    s = event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: what was the value of `axe.format_coord` before?

Comment: As can be seen from the error, you can't use `z` as an additional argument, as the lambda function is always called with 2 arguments (`x`,`y`).

Comment: Previous value was `axe.format_coord = lambda x, y: ''` wich worked perfectly as I also want to disable coordinates from the toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to suppress any output in the status bar of the figure window, one may replace the figure toolbar's message method (`NavigationToolbar2`'s `.set_message`) with a lambda function that returns an empty string:

```
fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message = lambda x: ""
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(np.random.rand(5,5))
fig.canvas.toolbar.set_message = lambda x: ""

plt.show()
```

Comment: I forget to mention that I was doing an GUI on Tkinter, tried your suggestion but wasn't working but then applied that to the toolbar widget with:     
     `self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.plot1_frame1) self.toolbar.set_message=lambda x:""`
And works fine, thank you